# Qt, Отправка клиенту его номера

Tags: qt, сервер, сеть, клиент

Есть клиент-серверная игра. Она пошаговая. Проходит между двумя игроками, сделано абсолютно всё, кроме пошаговой системы...
Основная беда в том, что с сетью работаю первый раз и еще не пришла мысль как реализовать нумерацию клиентов, поэтому обращаюсь сюда.

**Сам вопрос**

---

Как и в какой момент говорить клиенту что сейчас его ход?

#### Код сервера

```
void MyServer::sendToClient(const QString& str)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    ba = str.toStdString().c_str();

    for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); ++i)
    {
        QTextStream iod(clientList.at(i));
        iod << str;
    }
}
```

#### Код клиента

```
void gamescene::readFromServer()
{
    QByteArray ba = socket->readAll();
    QString dat = ba;
    //Если получаем команду от сервера "Shot", разрешаем клиенту выстрелить
    if(dat == "Shot")
    {
        shoted = true;
    }
    else if(dat == "Miss")
    {
        qDebug() << "Промах";
    }
    else if(dat == "Near")
    {
        score += 50;
        qDebug() << "+50 очков, ВСЕГО: " << score;
    }
    else if(dat == "100")
    {

        score += 100;
        qDebug() << "+100 очков, ВСЕГО: " << score;
    }
    else if(dat == "Start")
    {
        WaitTable->close();
    }
}
```

ba - команда для клиента.
Были попытки обращаться в цикле через условия, например if(i % 2 == 0),  это первый клиент, и отправить ему соответствующее сообщение. Но как-то не прижилась эта идея... Используемый сокет **TCP**

---

**Спасибо за уделенное время**

Comment: Уточните какой сокет вы используете - TCP или UDP.

Answer (score 2):

> В какой момент говорить клиенту что сейчас его ход

Мне неизвестна логика самой игры, наверное стоит это продумать именно Вам.

> Как

Клиенту при старте присваивается уникальный ID. Это может быть сделано непосредственно в коде клиента, либо это можно считывать из файла рядом с кодом клиента(фактически файл конфигурации, является более общим решением). Насколько я помню, в Qt при подключении нового клиента создается новый экземпляр класса, и Вы общаетесь как раз через этот экземпляр, записывая или считывая его. При подключении, клиент отправляет на сервер свой ID. Всё что Вам необходимо на сервере, это map с ID клиента и его классом для связи. Далее, Вы знаете кто есть кто, основываясь на ID уже определяется внутренней логикой программы кто когда ходит. Также, если у Вас всего 2 клиента, и задача, насколько я понимаю, состоит в том что бы просто определить кто первый кто второй, то можно просто считать первым того, кто первым подключился. Либо кинуть жребий, уже после подключения обоих. А если честно, то вопрос не до конца понятен, т.е. мне не понятно, в каком месте у Вас загвоздка. Если как-то прокомментируете, попробую дать более подробный и чёткий ответ.